# Double footerview in tableview when reload section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have uitableview footer that i create programatically like this:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {


CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45);
UIView *tableFooter = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
tableFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIButton* moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[moreButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moreImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[moreButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
moreButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;   

[moreButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
[tableFooter moreButton];

return tableFooter;

}
```

And somewhere in my code i retrieve again data from server and reload certain section using this:

```
 [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:mySection] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

However when the table present the new data i have two footer view on mysection, one with correct position, one just floating somewhere in my section. How i remove this footer?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your table's footerview nil?

Comment: @Voyager : A quick fix after downloading the data reload the whole tableView rather then section :) [self.tableView reloadData]